# Why is changing protected access in a base class to public access in a derived class allowed?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

In TypeScript this is legal code:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;

    constructor(theName: string) {
         this.name = theName;
    }

    protected move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) {
         super(name);
    }

    move(distanceInMeters = 5) {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) {
         super(name);
    }

    move(distanceInMeters = 45) {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}
```

However this would be illegal in C#, for example. Going from public to protected is not allowed in TypeScript, however.

What is the rationale for allowing a protected function to be exposed as a public function in a derived class? Coming from C# and Java, it doesn't make sense to me to allow the access level of a member to be changed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the rationale for allowing a protected function to be exposed as a public function in a derived class

It is allowed because its not disallowed. You are simply getting what you write (and since you didn't write the child became public as that is the default).

## More

Language Design https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/

> Going from public to protected is not allowed in TypeScript, however.

For good reason. Consider the following

```
class Animal {
    name: string;

    constructor(theName: string) {
         this.name = theName;
    }

    move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) {
         super(name);
    }

    protected move(distanceInMeters = 5) { // If allowed 
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

let snake = new Snake('slitherin');
snake.move(); // ERROR 
let foo: Animal = snake; 
foo.move(); // HAHA made my way around the error!
```